# How to upload AR marker creator to server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, augmented-reality, ar.js, jsartoolkit

I'm trying to use Carnaux's NFT marker creator (https://github.com/Carnaux/NFT-Marker-Creator), and upload it to my own server.
Basically I want a page that looks like this https://carnaux.github.io/NFT-Marker-Creator/#/ but on my own server.

I downloaded the files, but just uploading them to the server didn't work.
Do I have to use node.js? Any tips on how to configure that? Not sure where to start.

---

Edit:

Here's the link where I tried to upload the files to my test server
https://mar-test.000webhostapp.com/NFT-Creator-Web.html

You can upload an image, but not generate a marker.

I just downloaded the files from github by clicking the green "code" button and selecting "download zip", and then uploaded everything to the test server.

Seems like part of my problem is that I don't know how to use github to fork a repository. But shouldn't it work just by uploading the files to the server like this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean with "didn't work" ? Can you share log ?

Comment: I agree with @Elikill58, please describe the issue you found and what didn't work. Anyway, for testing, i suggest to you to fork the repository https://github.com/Carnaux/NFT-Marker-Creator, create a gh-pages branch and enabling GitHub Pages for that branch.